# logrotate: ротация логов с произвольными именами, каждый день - новые имена логов

Tags: linux, логирование

В `/var/log/1c_ws/` пишутся логи обмена (тело запроса - тело ответа). Каждая запись лога - отдельный файл с удобным для поиска именем:

- `request-order-{ID}.log` - запрос
- `response-order-{ID}.log` - ответ

`ID` - это номер заказа.

Нужна ротация таких логов: простая чистка устаревших, либо упаковка очередной порции логов за день в один архив и ротация архивов.

**Я могу написать bash-скрипт для этих целей и повесить на cron. А можно каким-либо образом использовать logrotate?**

logrotate работает таким способом:

`request-order-1.log` => `request-order-1.log.0` => `request-order-1.log.1` => ... => удаление.

Проблема заключается в том, что если файл `request-order-1.log` после очередной ротации не будет создан, ротация повиснет на уровне `request-order-1.log.0`. А файл не будет создан, каждый день - новые заказы, новые ID.

UPD. Пример конфига

```
# sudo logrotate /home/user/tmp/logroatate/ws.conf

/home/user/tmp/logroatate/var/*.log {
        daily
        rotate 1
        maxage 1
        missingok
        nocompress
        olddir /home/user/tmp/logroatate/var/old
}
```

Comment: просто установи `maxage` — он будет удалять старые ротированные логи независимо от того, превысили ли они другие лимиты (по количеству объёму или ещё чему-то). ЗЫ: в таком случае я бы ротировал логи в отдельный каталог...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, спасибо, что принимаете участие :) Я уже делал `maxage 1`, затем `touch -amd "7 days ago" мой-лог-файл`, и запускал `logrotate -f мой-кофиг`, но файлы остались лежать в том отдельном каталоге. Не работает. Ну может logrotate смотрит на stat "Изменен"... Попробую еще разок.

Comment: не... поидей он должен на `mtime` ориентироваться... добавь в вопрос что ли текущий вариант конфига на «поиграться»...

Comment: @Fat-Zer приложил конфиг, отлаживаюсь в своем `$HOME/tmp/logroatate`

Comment: «каждый день - новые заказы, новые ID» — что-то у меня такое чувство, что в такой ситуации bash-скрипт будет более правильным решением, logrotate всё-таки больше для постоянно существующих файлов предназначен

Comment: @andreymal, наверное, да. мне logrotate хотелось бы использовать больше по идеологическим причинам: есть штатный инструмент, нужно им пользоваться. и конфиги в одном месте, без изучения всех cron задач

Comment: @TotalPusher, мда... правда не работает посмотрел исходники — там тоже ничего подобного нет и каждый файл обрабатывается `maxage` отдельно и только в случае если он будет ротирован (читай «существует»)... не знаю, почему я был так уверен, что оно сработает =/... думаю это хорошее время написать разработчикам feature-request...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, решил добавлением своей команды в `postrotate`. feature-request это хорошо, но я посмотрел, пакет древний, там только багфиксы, вряд ли кто-то будет что-то туда добавлять из пожеланий, только если сам напишешь и отправишь. Да и вообще не логично удалять "старые", вдруг там в olddir что-то еще падает, банально - с другого конфига, и такая "фишка" станет "багом"

Comment: @TotalPusher, ИМХО это поведение на гране бага, и им бы и являлось если бы ни оговорка в man'е: «`The age is only checked if the logfile is to be rotated.`»... организовать удаление только файлов ротированных логов будет не сложно — `logrotate` сохраняет имена исходных файлов в state-файле... а проект с виду вполне живой несмотря на то что древний, но да, конечно, патч получил бы куда больше шансов быть принятым, чем FR, который с большой вероятностью будет висеть годами... но это одно из тех изменений, которые стоит обсудить прежде чем рашится в них...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавление команды зачистки `old` решило проблему. Конфиг logrotate такой:

```
/home/user/tmp/logroatate/var/*.log {
  daily
  rotate 3
  missingok
  nocompress
  sharedscripts
  olddir /home/user/tmp/logroatate/var/old

  postrotate
    find /home/user/tmp/logroatate/var/old -type f -mtime +4 -print0 | xargs -0 rm -f
  endscript
}
```

Секция `postrotate` не выполняется, если в каталоге нет файлов для ротации, меня это устраивает.