# logrotate для файлов с изменяющимися именами

Tags: linux, логирование

возник вопрос как делать ротацию файла, который генерируется каждый день
Система федора 7

students.auto-20200313
students.auto-20200314
.....
students.auto-20200512

чтобы хранило только файлы за последний день, а остальные удаляло автоматом? Спасибо за помощь, гуглом не разобрался как это сделать правильно.

Comment: `daily`. а дириктеву `rotate 0` можно и опусить — ноль там по умолчанию.

Comment: а, кажется, понял, в чём у вас трудность: имя файла должно быть статичным. сохраняйте его сразу под именем `students.auto` или что-нибудь в этом духе. или переименовывайте после сохранения, если создающая программа не умеет этого делать сразу.

Comment: верно, каждый день приписывает новые значения, тоесть это не реально сделать :(

Comment: я описываю, как сделать, вы пишете «то есть это не реально сделать». вам, конечно, виднее, реально или нет.

Comment: и, да, исходя из описания, вам ротация не нужна: нужно просто удалять существующий файл. для этого logrotate и не нужен. а если всё-таки одна ротация нужна, то в директиве `rotate` надо указывать параметр `1`

Comment: спасибо попробую сейчас добавить это.

Comment: связанные вопросы: [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1031272/178576) [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/958850/178576)